# How to detect if video is being handled by progressive download or streaming

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, progressive-download, brightcove

we are moving from progressive download architecture to a streaming/adaptive architecture for the videos. So is there an easy way to detect if the video is handled by progressive download or if it is streaming. I am not into flash, so it might be a newbie question, but can somebody give me their inputs as to how can I detect if it is progressive download or streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking in the case of UDS set up on your account? Otherwise I think the delivery method is established at the account level.
See the [Content delivery options doc](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/content-delivery-options#types)
You can check the forums for [some answers](http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/Flash-Only-Player-APIs/Progressive-or-streaming-download/m-p/11884/highlight/true#M1886)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just check all of your videos, use the [Media API](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/#Video_Read) and check the first four characters of the videoFullLength property. If the video is progressive download only, the url will begin "http". If it is streaming, it will begin "rtmp".

If you want to check the delivery of a video kduring playback, you could also use the Player API to get the information, using the [getCurrentVideo()](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/smart-player-api/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html#getCurrentVideo) method of the video player module, as this returns the [video DTO](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/media-api-objects-reference#Video).